# Oozie Error: E1310 : E1310: Bundle Job submission Error: [null]

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I created a oozie bundle consisting of several coordinators and respective workflows.  The bundle ran fine previously but with adding a new workflow it stopped working completely.

For simplification and debugging I stripped the bundle down to the absolute minimum consisting of one coordinator starting one workflow.

The XMLs seem to be valid (validated with oozie) and the coordinator and workflow is working fine on their own (with fitting properties).

Problem is, that I do not get any meaningful errors on -dryrun or run.
Dryrun is producing the error: `Error: E1310 : E1310: Bundle Job submission Error: [null]` which does not lead me anywhere.

Just running the job results in the bundle being submitted and markes as "FAILED" with no coordinator started. Therefore I do not get any error reports on the coordinator to work with.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with the coordinator and workflow and the propagation of the variables from the bundle.properties file to the coordinator and the workflow I found a couple of important things to take note of that solved my problem in the end:

1. -dryrun on a bundle does not work as intended it seems. The above error is persistent even after fixing the bundle to run fine in oozie. I could not find anything noting that dryrun is not supported on bundles but the `[null]` is indicating that dryrun can not handle bundles
2. HDFS Paths have to be added with port numbers to work correctly. I had several paths in the format of `hdfs://nodename/hdfs/dir/....` that did not seem to be propagated correctly without the correct path in the format of `hdfs://nodename:8020/hdfs/dir/...`. After adding the portnumber they worked fine
3. I missed a couple of variables in the bundle.xml that were used in the coordinator.xml. This did not get reported by oozie at all but instead followed in the coordinator not being started at all. The bundle will just be listed with -info  without any sheduled coordinators with the status "running". This is pretty hard to debug because of missing feedback on oozie. Make sure to test your coordinator with a properties file and use that "working" properties file as a schema to check the bundle.properties and .xml for any missed variable